# Finite dimensional vector space is finitely generated and a torsion module

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Let $M={}_{\mathbb{R}[X]}V$ be the $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module defined in the usual way from $V$ and $T$.

Explain why $M$ is finitely generated and is a torsion module.

---

My thought on why $M$ is finitely generated is that since $M$ has the same underlay set as $V$. $V$ is finite dimensional meaning the basis for $V$ has finitely many elements, so do the basis for $M$.

For the torsion module part, am I suppose to show for all $u \in M$, there exist a $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]\setminus\{0\}$ such that $fu=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $M$ is the $\mathbb{R}[X]$ module constructed by letting $X$ act on $V$ through $T$, right? In that case, $M$ is finitely-generated as a vector space and thus also as a module. You're correct about the torsion module part; use the fact that for any $v\in V$, the vectors $v, Tv, \dots, T^n v$ can't be linearly independent for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean in the first part "letting $X$ act ..." I think this question can be done without considering the map $T$. Since there is a second part of the question. And what do you mean by can't be linearly independent for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: I mean that $X$ act on the module $M$ by $T$: for all $v\in V$, we have $X.v = T(v)$. The first part of the question is asking whether $M$ is generated as a {\it module}, not as a vector space; normally the action of $X$ would matter, but $M$ is already a finitely-generated $\mathbb{R}$-module (i.e., $\mathbb{R}$-vector space) and so is also a finitely-generated $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module. For the latter, I mean that the $n + 1$ vectors $v, Tv, \dots T^n v\in V$ can't be linearly independent if $n \geq \dim V$.